# If $a+b+c=0$ find $\frac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{b^2-ca}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried finding the value of $a^2+b^2+c^2$ and it is $-2(ab+bc+ca)$ but that doesn't have any common factor with $b^2-ca$ so that didn't help.
I squared on both sides of $a+b=-c$ to get $a^2+b^2-c^2+2ab=0$. But I didn't proceed any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple algebra to verify$$\frac{a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2}{b^2+a(a+b)}=2$$provided the denominator is nonzero, but it's $(a+b/2)^2+3b^2/4$, so that only requires $a,\,b$ to not both be $0$.

Answer (score 3):

$0 = 0^2 = (a + b + c)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2  + 2ab + 2ac + 2bc$

$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = -2(ab + ac + bc)$

$b² - ac = -b(a + c) - ac = -(ab + ac + bc)$  as  $b = -(a + c)$

Hence, the answer is 2.

Answer (score 0):

With $b = \lambda a, c = \mu a$

$$
\frac{1+\lambda^2+\mu^2}{\lambda^2+\mu}=\frac{1+\lambda^2+(1+\lambda)^2}{\lambda^2+\lambda+1} = 2
$$